# What is the longest proposition reference chain in Euclid's Elements?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, math-history

For example, Prop. 12.9 reffers to Prop. 11.34, which refers to Prop. 12.31, which reffers to....

Has this ever been studied? If we did this for every Proposition, I think we would have a very interesting directed graph.

Comment: See https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/46/Boman-Euclid21/BigGraph.png from https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/euclid21-euclids-elements-for-the-21st-century-what-we-have-wrought

Comment: @Henry, thank you, very interesting!